# How can I rewrite parent class UIButton property in subclass?

Tags: ios, swift

Basically my question is simple, I have a button property in my "DNAParentViewController" UIViewController, it's:

```
var doneButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.customizedButtonStyle(title: "Done", bgColor: .clear, titleColor: .white, isBold: false, titleFontSize: 15)
    return button
}()
```

I have 3 child classes name is "CharacteristicsViewController" and other 2(names doesn't matter) which inherits "DNAParentViewController" and I wanna customize and rewrite each doneButton's click target by using `button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToNext), for: .touchUpInside)` in each different child class' viewDidLoad. However, after I did so for 3 of them, none of their goToNext in each view controller got triggered.

What I want is just let them to go to different places after clicking the doneButton in different child classes, how should I do that? Thanks.

Here is the whole code snipt for easily view them:

**DNAParentViewController.swift:**

```
class DNAParentViewController: UIViewController {
    var doneButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.customizedButtonStyle(title: "Done", bgColor: .clear, titleColor: .white, isBold: false, titleFontSize: 15)
        return button
    }()
}
```

**CharacteristicsViewController.swift(another 2 are same):**

```
 class CharacteristicsViewController: DNAParentViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        customizsGUI()
    }

    func customizsGUI() {
        doneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToGrowthAreas), for: .touchUpOutside)
    }

    //MARK: - Action Handlers
    @objc func goToGrowthAreas() {
        print("lalalalalalalal")
        navigationController?.pushViewController(GrowthAreasViewController(), animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the better way to do around is to create an `ExtensionClass`. Create a new swift file and name it as `App+Extensions.swift`. Now, once it is created defined, created an extension for `UIButton`.

```
import UIKit

extension UIButton {
func customizsGUI(vc: UIViewController) {
    self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToGrowthAreas), for: .touchUpOutside)
}

@objc func goToGrowthAreas(vc: UIViewController) {
    print("lalalalalalalal")

    vc.navigationController?.pushViewController(GrowthAreasViewController(), animated: true)

 }
}
```

Now, you can call it like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
doneButton.customizsGUI(vc: self)
}
```

This way, you can call this function on any button, without worrying about `Parent` and `Sub` Class. Also, there are some different ways of passing the `VC`, but it will do the task for you.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want is just let them to go to different places after clicking
>   the doneButton in different child classes, how should I do that?
>   Thanks.

1) Simply move `customizsGUI()` function which you intend to use for modifying the `doneButton`'s target, to your parent class.

2) Override that function in your subclass and customise it to your needs

A snippet to explain what I'm talking about:

> Child classes can replace parent methods with their own
>   implementations – a process known as overriding.

So, here's what it would probably look like after doing all of this:

```
class DNAParentViewController: UIViewController {
    var doneButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.customizedButtonStyle(title: "Done", bgColor: .clear, titleColor: .white, isBold: false, titleFontSize: 15)
        return button
    }()

    //Move the method here, and override it in your child classes
    func customiseGUI() {
        doneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToGrowthAreas), for: .touchUpOutside)
    }

    @objc func goToGrowthAreas() {
        print("lalalalalalalal")
        navigationController?.pushViewController(UIViewController(), animated: true)
    }
}

class YourSubclass: DNAParentViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    //This overrides the parent method, and executes this piece of code wherever you use this subclass
    override func customiseGUI() {
        doneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doSomethingElse), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func doSomethingElse() {

    }

}
```

Hope this helps!